# Angularjs route going into infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, routes

my app combines Angular with .net MVC. Its is suppose to load the index.cshtml
page on start but it goes into an infinite loop reloading the _Layout.cshtml page. I have tried reading other posts and everything I have tried seems not to work. Below are my files

app.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('sbslsApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/Home/Index', controller: '', title: 'Home Screen' })
        .when('/Invoice', { templateUrl: '/Invoice/Index', controller: '', title: 'Invoice List' })
        .when('/Invoice/Create', { templateUrl: '/Invoice/Create', controller: '', title: 'Create New Invoice' })
        .when('/Invoice/Edit', { templateUrl: '/Invoice/Edit', controller: '', title: 'Edit Invoice' })
        .when('/Invoice/Delete', { templateUrl: '/Invoice/Delete', controller: '', title: 'Delete Invoice' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop problem can be avoided by setting base href to '/' instead of document.location and by prefixing templateUrls with '/'.

For details, please see: [AngularJs Infinite Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259890/angularjs-infinite-loop)

Comment: Hi Ben. I already have both base href set to '/' and prefixed templateUrl with '/' and am still getting that problem

Comment: Can u try turn on the Developer mode and check on which pages are called in which sequence ?

Comment: the followed by "localhost:8080/home/index"

Comment: Will you be able to specify separate controllers for each routes ?